# Installing Pillow on MacOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

The default Python is 2.7 that's come prebuilt into the OS.

When trying to install Pillow using the commands:

> sudo pip install Pillow

It installs it into my Python 2.7 direction, rather than the latest 3.x version I've installed. How do I go about solving this issue? Is there a way to point the installer to the correct directory?

Comment: Use pip3 to install for python3. `sudo pip3 install Pillow`

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I think that worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this? Moreover, read about homebrew installation (Homebrew, pillow, pip).

```
Sudo pip3 install Pillow
```